# Weird "shift" when google maps javascript api v3 loads

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm getting a weird "shift" once the maps are completely loaded, see here: http://screencast.com/t/0IvcvNbHCl, here is my embed code: http://pastebin.com/hvN5sgEp any suggestions on how to get rid of it?

Comment: I think it's something in your CSS handling. I'd need to see a real live link to the site itself to be sure though.

Comment: It's on our development server behind a password. If you want to email me, I can send you the password. (briandichiara@gmail.com)

Comment: Can you make a CSS suggestion? I tried .location-map div { padding:0; margin:0; } but didn't seem to help.

Comment: Just going through some old questions and checked the site on this (http://www.americanpipe.com/about-us/our-locations/). It appears to have resolved itself. Sorry I don't have any other information on it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to happen if you don't set a width (or min-width) to the element that the map is rendered in, or if you set that width to a too-small value.

Also see this duplicate topic: [Google Maps v3 Shifting After Loading in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904638/google-maps-v3-shifting-after-loading-in-wordpress)