# Google Maps v3 Shifting After Loading in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

The page loads with Google Maps and doesn't initially fill the container surrounding it.
Half second later Google maps fills up the container.

The problem is it's distorted after the container is properly filled.
The longitude lines because of the shift show two of them right next to each other.
And the map controls are distorted as well. Can't even tell the zoom bar is there.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

This is part of a Wordpress plugin that I just started building.

I can't post pictures yet or I would!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in the default theme wordpress uses.
The below line of code outlines it was only allowing it to go to 97.5% of the width it needed to messing up google maps.

`.entry-content img, .comment-content img, .widget img { max-width: 97.5%; }`

Correct code (or what worked for me):

`.entry-content img, .comment-content img, .widget img { max-width: none; }`

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced this issue before a few times, not with wordpress as i steer clear from that package.. But two causes i had we...

One would only occur each time after the map was viewed/loaded and that was due to the gmaps external script call being loaded more then once.

The second was due to a relative/absolute position element that was affecting the maps block element... I cant recall 100% as been a few weeks since that..

How are you handling the onload events and so forth...

Comment: I'm using jQuery and on document ready it's loading the google map apis to load the map. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: Yep.. and to confirm when you say on document ready, are you loading it via the jquerys onload event handler or the default body onload='' .... as i dont trust the body method..

Try reordering your onload/init script... but its hard to guess this one without a little more insight... Can you post a few example lines or something like that... say the line holding the google box element and the general map load script

Comment: I'm using jQuery $(document).ready(function(){ calling google's initialize function here });

Comment: Still need to see a little more or explain a little more, If the map loads in general then the doc/ready/init is working fine.. So this would come down to the actual script for the map or something relating to the element that contains it. have you removed the bare script and tested in a blank page to see if the issue follows the script or stays with the project itself

Comment: I will try it on a blank page. I will post the code after if it doesn't work. Thank you very much for your responses!

Comment: as a general rule for myself... if it stops working or something is a glitch/bug... i'll extract the overall script/section and test it external from the main project... that way it either stays with one or the other and at least gives a good direction and can speed up time to find the bug

Comment: Well I have tested it on a blank page and everything is working fine. So I know it has to do with either Wordpress or the way I'm loading my scripts. Thank you very much again!

Comment: I believe I have found the issue and it was due to the standard theme that comes with Wordpress.

The issue was with:
`.entry-content img, .comment-content img, .widget img { max-width: 97.5%; }`

What is the proper way to display the correct solution so if anyone else comes across it is easy for them to find?

Comment: So the issue itself was with the max-width..
I generally have not used a element for the map that resizes on creation or during operation of the map. My guess is that the canvas of google maps is not getting updated... So there maybe a quick fix that will allow you to reload the canvas or redraw/resize the canvas every time the page is loaded. Try wrapping the maps div/element/container with a set width div/element... this way it may keep the sizing ??

Comment: Yes, that was the issue. It's a part of the default theme in Wordpress. I set the max-width: none and everything is working great.  I did have a container around it set to a fixed width. That was why I was extremely confused.

Comment: So things are all good now? If you can rename this posts title and add wordpress, that should help in the searches for future ppl? Not sure if this site does as still new here

Comment: Yup things are good! I renamed the title, good idea. Thank you again for your help I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

I decided to write a answer to could help somebody else with same problem.

I stumbled upon this problem recently and had same problem plus something else. Google maps zoom bar wasn't visible and every image had a nice gray border :)  All problems because of default styles in **twentythirteen** theme:

```
/* Responsive images */
.entry-content img,
.comment-content img,
.widget img {
    max-width: 100%; /* Fluid images for posts, comments, and widgets */
}
```

and lower

```
.entry-content img,
.comment-content img,
.widget img,
img.header-image,
.author-avatar img,
img.wp-post-image {
    /* Add fancy borders to all WordPress-added images but not things like badges and icons and the like */
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

I had my google-map object in a div with id = map_canvas. Solution was to add in my styles overwrites of above styles:

```
 #map-canvas img {
     max-width: none!important;
    border-radius: none!important;
    box-shadow: none!important;
 }
```

Voila ! The map is clean :)