# Google Map loaded two times

Tags: wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Maps v3 Shifting After Loading in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904638/google-maps-v3-shifting-after-loading-in-wordpress)

I used the code generated with this useful tool: http://powerhut.co.uk/googlemaps/custom_markers.php

This is my html before < / head > tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function initializeMap()
    {
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(42.61196, 12.54584);

        myOptions = {
            zoom: 13,
            center: point,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
            '/wp-content/plugins/comprehensive-google-map-plugin/assets/css/images/markers/medicine.png',
            new google.maps.Size(32,37),
            new google.maps.Point(0,0),
            new google.maps.Point(16,37)
        );

        var shape = {
            coord: [29,0,30,1,31,2,31,3,31,4,31,5,31,6,31,7,31,8,31,9,31,10,31,11,31,12,31,13,31,14,31,15,31,16,31,17,31,18,31,19,31,20,31,21,31,22,31,23,31,24,31,25,31,26,31,27,31,28,31,29,30,30,29,31,23,32,22,33,21,34,20,35,19,36,12,36,11,35,10,34,9,33,8,32,2,31,1,30,0,29,0,28,0,27,0,26,0,25,0,24,0,23,0,22,0,21,0,20,0,19,0,18,0,17,0,16,0,15,0,14,0,13,0,12,0,11,0,10,0,9,0,8,0,7,0,6,0,5,0,4,0,3,0,2,1,1,2,0,29,0],
            type: 'poly'
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), myOptions);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            title: "Marker Title",
            position: point,
            icon: image,
            shape: shape
        });
        var window = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "<b>Marker Title</b>",
            maxWidth: 150
        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(window);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
            infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }
</script>
```

On body:

```
<body onload="initializeMap();">
```

Inside body...

```
<div id="googleMap">&nbsp;</div>
```

...and the style...

```
#googleMap {
    width: 540px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
```

I'm using Wordpress and the map seems to be loaded two times, creating a smoothing effect and corrupting some commands.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's hard to make changes there, could you update an example on http://jsfiddle.net/?

Comment: on jsfiddle.net all works fine... there is something in wordpress environment that is annoying my script :( => http://jsfiddle.net/GBnJV/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your map is only loading once. The problem is WordPress styles. See [Google Maps v3 Shifting After Loading in Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904638/google-maps-v3-shifting-after-loading-in-wordpress)